# Alexa Validation exception in class error

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

On my Alexa ListTemplate I am getting this error. On some titles it works and on some not. Do you know what is causing this issue?

```
Validation exception in class: TripleTextContent Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I did figure out.
I was getting an `&` character to the title in the template and therefore I was receiving this problem. So for everybody, check your texts you are putting into the template if they contain an `&` symbol.